# Having difficulty in position a div that slides using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitladhania/Qa7Aa/). As you wil see that the cost div is positioned relatively but I want to position it absolutely. However positioning it absolutely send it to the bottom of the page.

```
.wrapper
{
width:200px;
height:200px;
border:solid 2px red;
}
.container
{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:#000;
position:;
}
.image
{
position:;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background-image:url(http://www.sat2home.com/satspacer//mobile/MobileTV.jpg);
background-position:50% 50%;
background-size:contain;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
z-index:1;
}
.cost
{
position:relative;
height:30px;
left:0px;
right:0px;
bottom:0px;
background-color:red;
color:#000;
font-size:13px;
padding-top:170px;
transition:all linear 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all linear 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: where should the cost(red)div should be placed? at the top?

Comment: no at the bottom of container div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `.wrapper` elements position to either `relative` or `absolute`.

```
.wrapper
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:solid 2px red;
    position:relative;
}
```

Because `absolute` elements are positioned based on the `closest ancestor that is absolutely or relatively positioned.`

This should even work if you set the same for `.container` element

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qa7Aa/4/)**

Comment: thanks mate help alot. i would just like to ask an easy question that i have made a site and and defined every element's width and height using % but when i see it in my laptop i happen to dont like the way it is show so i want to define the percentage differently for laptops what should i do

Comment: @AnkitLadhania.. Glad  to have helped :)

Comment: have you seen the post that i have sent sushanth

Comment: For that try setting the `max-height` and the `max-width` property so that it will not expand over a certain boundry

Comment: is there any other solution to that

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the follow rule in your `div.container`:

```
div.container { position: relative; }
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qa7Aa/3/):

Answer (score 0):

adding  `position:relative;` to `container` class does the trick.

```
.container
{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:#000;
position:;
}
```

Add `position: absolute` to the `cost` class

```
.cost
{
    position:absolute;
    height:30px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:red;
    color:#000;
    font-size:13px;
    padding-top:170px;
    transition:all linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.cost
{ 
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    top:200px;
    left:10px;
    right:0px;
    /*bottom:0px;*/
    background-color:red;
    color:#000;
    font-size:13px;
    /*padding-top:170px;*/
    transition:all linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Did some modifications in ur fiddle- [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ishankdubey/AkHuw/)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Ankit you can give the `position:relative;` to your `container` **div** and than if you will give the `position:absolute;` to your `cost` **div** so it will not go to the bottom of the page see the updated css :-

**Basically if your parent div is with position:relative; and your child div with 
position:absolute; so therefore your child div will be under the control of your parent div and will not go automatically anywhere out of the parent div**

**CSS**

```
.wrapper
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:solid 2px red;
}
.container
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#000;
    position:relative;
}
.image
{
    position:;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-image:url(http://www.sat2home.com/satspacer//mobile/MobileTV.jpg);
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    z-index:1;
}
.cost
{
    position:absolute;
    height:30px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:red;
    color:#000;
    font-size:13px;
    padding-top:170px;
    transition:all linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qa7Aa/7/)